# What alternatives are there to ClickOnce?

Tags: .net, wix, clickonce, web-deployment

I've used [ClickOnce](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ClickOnce) a lot over the years, but I have run up against a lot of its limitations. What alternatives are there for web deployment?

So far the only one I've been able to turn up is [ClickThrough](https://web.archive.org/web/20151226075116/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/robmen/archive/2005/11/08/490448.aspx), which is part of [WiX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WiX) now on the back burner. Are there others that have had success?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

After using WiX, NSIS and InstallAware, I have to humbly admit that they were all overkill for what I really need as a software developer. There are no projects that I've done so far which couldn't be deployed using the Visual Studio deployment project.

Is it limited? Yes.

It is also *very* simple to learn and use. Moreover, you *can* actually do really neat things like automatically create *patches* (.MSP files) by using techniques as described [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/install/dotnetpatching.aspx)

I fully understand that you can't do *everything* inside of a Visual Studio setup project, but it's rather surprising what you *can* accomplish. It's free, it's easy and, frankly, for general use is a better option than spending endless hours learning WiX's mind-boggling XML (impressive as it is), or InstallAware's verbose scripts.

With VS Setup, it's drag'n'drop & build'n'deploy. Every other solution I've tried had set backs... they can't automatically detect your project output... or need special filters so as not to include unwanted outputs from the build.

My suggestion is thus: If you simply wish to get your project deployed, then learn:

1. How to build a custom installer class, and
2. How to author your own pre-requisite packages

These are both reasonably easy skills to master, and satisfy the needs of most developers.

Comment: Visual Studio Setup projects cannot be build with MsBuild so if you are automating your release process they are a no go.

Comment: .vdproj (VS Setup Projects) have been dropped from VS2012.

Comment: .vdproj is now supported in VS 2013 https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/9abe329c-9bba-44a1-be59-0fbf6151054d

Comment: Visual Studio setup projects are ***not*** available in some [Express](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio_Express) versions of Visual Studio (all Express versions?).

Comment: @ErikEJ and its still poor support

Comment: Yeah, I spent several years becoming an expert at VS Setup only to have it discontinued.  Though it's overkill, I use VIX now because it seems to have the closest set of features.

Comment: "Microsoft Visual Studio Installer Projects" can be added to Visual Studio via "Manage Extensions"

Answer (score 31):

[Squirrel](https://github.com/Squirrel/Squirrel.Windows): It's like ClickOnce, but it works.

Squirrel is both a set of tools and a library, to completely manage both installation and updating your desktop Windows application, written in either C# or any other language (that is, Squirrel can manage native C++ applications).

Squirrel uses [NuGet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NuGet) packages to create installation and update packages, which means that you probably already know most of what you need to create an installer.

Comment: Squirrel for windows does not support Windows XP or .net 4.0, but if can live with that then its a great choice.

Comment: Squirrel.Windows is a great alternative to ClickOnce.  I've completed a migration from ClickOnce to Squirrel and it has gone smoothly at every step.  I've put a lot of time into making sure I understand all the facets that could affect my migration and the pay off so far seems worth the investment.

Comment: Hm it doesn't have any dialogs or GUI to guide the user through the update process? Just silently copies files around in the background?

Answer (score 5):

What limitations are you experiencing with ClickOnce? When I don't use ClickOnce, I use [NSIS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nullsoft_Scriptable_Install_System) (though you could use most other installer languages/systems) to make a runnable, self-installing application.

That is, when you run the download it is running the application, and there aren't any setup questions. There is a menu option, or a frequent-use detector that allows for permanent installation.

The two hard issues are:

1. Settings files
2. Local registry settings

For settings files, I use a remote web service to hold states, etc.

If you need local registry settings (file associations, etc.) then you need to do a proper install, but this can be done silently when the user is working with the application for the first time.

Comment: nsis installs are not vaild for "design for" logo.
you have to use windows installer and i think it isnt a good idea to use legacy installers.

Comment: NSIS is hardly legacy, it stil solves many issues not easily resolved in WIX etc

Have you ever had a customer ask for "designed for" compliance?

Deliver a sound solution that the customer want's, not what the Microsoft marketing dept want!

Comment: @TFD NSIS is no good for corporate customers, if it's not MSI then it's not getting rolled out to 1000+ machines.

Comment: @sascha We are talking about processes that are NOT deployed via corporate rollout mechanisms. That's what ClickOnce is for

Comment: You can use WIX if you want, but NSIS is so much easier, and the result is the same

Comment: Clickonce just breaks every once in a while for one computer in ten, or one update in ten. It'll always find a way to break for the least technical person who is in most need of you app at that moment in time. So that's the biggest consistency for me - lack of reliability.

Answer (score 3):

Check this out
http://simpldeploy.com
It‘s similar to squirrel but integrated into VS like ClickOnce. And it has Dialogs (optional) like ClickOnce.

Comment: I liked this option, it's a lot more simple than Squirrel. But unfortunately, it isn't a complete replacement for ClickOnce. It only works with URLs and it currently doesn't support file servers/UNC paths for deployment. The author said that they have that in their backlog, but unfortunately it doesn't seem like it's going to be implemented any time soon. :(

Comment: Yes that‘s an issue indeed. What we did for environments where no public domain was avalaible we just set up an iis and published it to a servers url (http://myinternalserver/apps/myapp)

Comment: i had a different issue when trying out this one. first was an error caused by a missing `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.15.0.dll` which i don't know why as i'm using VS Pro 2017 to begin with. so i downloaded it via NuGet, installed it to my GAC using gacutil, and now i get this log entry: https://pastebin.com/RNLhx2Zi

Comment: There was an issue with VS 2017 in Version 2.0.0. This has been fixed now in current Version 2.0.1. Thank you