# JAVA: Get Filename from http urls with file ID

Tags: java, php

To get **HTTP** links with direct link to file (with **NAME** and **EXTENSION**) 
like `http://website.com/file.avi` could be done with

```
URL FileLocation = new URL("string");
String Name = FileLocation.getFile();
```

which would return **NAME** with **EXTENSION** (/filename.ext)

but How to get Filename for **URLs** with php ID like

```
http:///website.com/download.php?d=9594
```

I want to do this in JAVA only.

Comment: What do you want to get? `9594`?

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12250258/12252255#12252255) link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to look for `Content-Disposition` field in the header of HTTP response, e.g.

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="fname.ext"
```

Since it is in the HTTP header, you will need to start downloading the message first before getting the file name. Here is an example of [how you use URLConnection and how to get a header field](http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.net/GetHeaders.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
 File file=new File("C:/work/chandan/deepak.txt");
  URL url=null;
 ....
 ....

url=file.toURL(); //file:/C:/work/chandan/deepak.txt
System.out.println("The url is" + url);
```