# WiX exception at very beginning

Tags: c#, .net, wix

I downloaded Wix V3.0 and installed. An unhandled exception happened each time when I tried to use the Click Through for Isolated Applications type. So i cannot use it. [image]

we are using .Net 3.5 we cannot upgrade to .Net 4. anybody knows a workaround?

thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[According to Rob Mensching Wed, 10 Dec 2008 08:48:22 -0800](http://www.mail-archive.com/wix-users@lists.sourceforge.net/msg24149.html)

**ClickThrough has significant bugs that have all been punted to WiX v4 
essentially rendering ClickThrough useless until then.**

This is relatively old but I think this is still the current stance on it. I've never personally toyed with with Click through but, from personal exp, The simpler you can make your wix install the better. In terms of keeping it close to the metal.

Oh and this might be of help to you if your still wanting to go the automation route
 [Alternatives to Click One](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/623418/what-alternatives-are-there-to-clickonce)