# ClickOnce - installing an app gives 'Cannot Start Application' error

Tags: installation, clickonce

I have a simple windows application which I want to distribute through a website which is running on Azure. I publish the app locally first and then manually copy over the artifacts to the web server at location ../fold/apps/tools

Publish location: C:\Users\MyUsername\Documents\publish
Installation folder URL: https://somewebsite/fold/apps/tools/
Update location is same as the installation folder.

The files copied over are "Application Files" folder, Myapp.application, publish.htm and setup.exe.

Now I log onto the website and download the app using https://somewebsite/fold/apps/tools/Myapp.application

Clickling on the downloaded files shows me the 'Cannot Start Application' popup. Clicking on the details button shows the following error in the log file.

SOURCES
Deployment url      : file:///C:/Users/MyUsername/Downloads/Myapp.application
Deployment Provider url : https://somewebsite/fold/apps/tools/Myapp.application

ERROR SUMMARY
    Below is a summary of the errors, details of these errors are listed later in the log.
    * Activation of C:\Users\MyUsername\Downloads\Myapp.application resulted in exception. Following failure messages were detected:
    + The Deployment Provider specified in the manifest cannot be reached. Maybe due to network error and/or the deployment provider is not responding correctly.
    + Exception reading manifest from https://somewebsite/login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2ffold%2ftools%2fMyapp.application: the manifest may not be valid or the file could not be opened.
    + DTD is prohibited in this XML document.
I don’t understand why it tries to redirect to the login page when I am logged in. To test I placed a simple text file in the same location as the .application file and was able to access it after logging in.

Please let me know where the issue might be.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that 'You cannot use forms authentication with ClickOnce deployment'. See [Use ClickOnce on password protected web site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4483924/use-clickonce-on-password-protected-web-site).
I ended up opening up the folder to the world by placing a Web.config file with 
    `<system.web>
           <authorization>
              <allow users="?"/>
           </authorization>
        </system.web>`
It was OK for me as the windows app doesn't need to be password protected.