# How to auto update a .net application?

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, auto-update

I have an application in .net 3.5 C#.

How to update my application and install updates automatically, whenever there is new release available for my application?

Comment: Please see this about ClickOnce:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/142dbbz4%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

Comment: And also please see this previously asked question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/691663/auto-update-library-for-net

Comment: I think this is what you need:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t71a733d%28v=vs.90%29.ASPX

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is countless ways which you can do this.

One provided by Microsoft that even Google Chrome uses is called ClickOnce.

There are numerous tutorials online below is just a few:

1. ClickOnce MSDN, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t71a733d%28v=vs.90%29.ASPX
2. http://weblogs.asp.net/shahar/archive/2008/01/29/how-to-use-clickonce-to-deploy-your-applications.aspx
3. http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/37db1d/deploying-wpf-application-with-clickonce-deployment-techniques/

There are other third party frameworks too as an example see http://autoupdaterdotnet.codeplex.com/

A good question in stack about alternatives to clickonce is a good start if ClickOnce is not what you are looking for: [What alternatives are there to ClickOnce?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/623418/what-alternatives-are-there-to-clickonce)

As commented by other posters you can see other questions in stackoverflow about this topic.

[Auto-update library for .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/691663/auto-update-library-for-net)