# Alternative to ClickOnce

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, clickonce

So I have been looking around for a way to have a window form application (c#) check for an update each time it's launched and even send a message to an active user that an update is required. This entire program will be ran in a S:\ (shared) folder. I know some one else recommend click once but everything I can find in it is from Visual Studio 2005 and well that's out dated. Anybody know a different one?

Comment: Search for SimpleUpdater or AutoUpdater.Net

Comment: Isn't click once built in to VS 2013? I'm pretty sure that's one of the **Publish** feature options. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t71a733d(v=vs.120).aspx

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What alternatives are there to ClickOnce?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/623418/what-alternatives-are-there-to-clickonce)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try https://github.com/squirrel/squirrel.windows

And intro to this on dotnetconf 2015: https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/dotnetConf/2015/Squirrel-for-Windows-installing-NET-apps-the-way-it-should-be

Answer (score 0):

You could give this a try https://simpldeploy.com

It's a bit different to squirrel, it's integrated into VS and does not require scripting altough it can be automated with the simplDeploy.packager.exe found in the extensions install dir.