# The best way to update WPF application

Tags: wpf, wix, auto-update

what is the best way to update WPF application? I use WiX as an installer, so how can I alert users of a newer version of my program? I think ClickOnce can't be used in combination with WiX installer.

Comment: Not sure this is a duplicate but good info here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/623418/what-alternatives-are-there-to-clickonce

Comment: in there was Squirrel https://github.com/Squirrel/Squirrel.Windows